# Dynamic form with Kendo React

Tags: reactjs, telerik, kendo-react-ui

I need to build a form dynamically using kendo react.

I came across the following article which demonstrates how to do this:
https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-programmatically-add-input-fields-react-forms

However, I noticed that the above article does not make use kendo form and kendo components. It also handles state through the onchange events.
Is it possible to build a dynamic form using Telerik Form and Field components? If I add kendo react Field components at runtime, would the kendo Form automatically manage the state (without needing the onchange events)?